# Android AnimationDrawable multi images at the same time

Tags: android, animation

I need to start blinking with four images. I start animation for each with for loop. When thy start blinking the animation is not sinhronised.

The affect that I want to achieve is for images to blink at the same time. How can I do that?

code:
inside array are four image resources

```
for(AnimationDrawable image : array){
  AnimationDrawable animationDrawable = (AnimationDrawable) image.getBackground();
  animationDrawable.start();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you dont have to use a loop for this. After you created your tween animation resource file (inflated it to `AnimationDrawable`), set it as the `android:src` for an `ImageView`, then in your code, simple call this like you did there:

`AnimationDrawable animationDrawable = (AnimationDrawable) image.getBackground();`

In your Activity, override the `public void onWindowFocusChange()` and start the animation like this:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus)
{
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    animationDrawable.start();
}
```

The reason why you need to override that method is because, you just want to start the animation as soon as the window has focus, or becomes interactive with the user. Hope this helps.

You create tween animation resource like this, you reference by its file name, and it must be put in the `drawable` folder

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:oneshot="false">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/yourDrawable1" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/yourDrawable2" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/yourDrawable3" android:duration="200" />
</animation-list>
```

Comment: I believe you mean Frame animation, not Tween animation. The Tween animation is used to animate and modify a single drawable, while Frame animation lets you put different drawables in the sequence your answer provides. Here is documentation: "-Tween animation: Creates an animation by performing a series of transformations on a single image with an Animation.
-Frame animation: or creates an animation by showing a sequence of images in order with an AnimationDrawable" -found at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html#Frame

Answer (score 0):

This is work for me :

```
int []mImageArray = {R.drawable.img1, R.drawable.img2, R.drawable.img3};

final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() 
{
  int i = 0;
  public void run() 
  {
    mImageView.setImageResource(mImageArray[i]);
    i++;
    if (i > mImageArray.length - 1)
    {
        i = 0;    
    }
    mHandler.postDelayed(this, 500);  // Set the interval delay
  }
  };
  mHandler.postDelayed(runnable, 4000); // Set the initial delay
}
```